# How to invoke groovy templates in the Jenkins email-ext plugin

Tags: groovy, jenkins, continuous-integration, email-ext

I want to use the Groovy scripting feature in the email-ext plugin for Jenkins, but I'm new to this and there seems to be a lot of assumed knowledge. Like how one goes about invoking one of these templates in the first place.

The answer to this is probably quite obvious, but I'm feeling a bit lost and would appreciate being pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This example is based on the official [email-ext documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin), which unfortunately does not provide any concrete examples on how to use the `$SCRIPT` line of code in Pipeline. If you wish to use an HTML template as the body for your email then you need to:

1. Create a template file called `my-email.template` or whatever you like - you can find some template examples [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/email-ext-plugin/tree/master/src/main/resources/hudson/plugins/emailext/templates)

   ```
   <body>
     <h3>Using "build" environment variables:</h3>
     <p>
       <a href="<%= build.absoluteUrl %>"><%= build.fullDisplayName %></a>
     </p>
     <h3>List of all available "build" environment variables:</h3>
     <div>
       <% println build.properties.collect{it}.join('<br />') %>
     </div>
   </body>
   ```
2. Have your Jenkins administrator place the `my-email.template` file inside `$JENKINS_HOME\email-templates` directory on Jenkins machine - make sure that user **jenkins** owns this directory as well as its content (i.e. template files)
3. In Pipeline load `my-email.template` as body content:

   ```
   stage('Send email') {
       def mailRecipients = "jenkins-user@example.com"
       def jobName = currentBuild.fullDisplayName

       emailext body: '''${SCRIPT, template="my-email.template"}''',
       subject: "[Jenkins] ${jobName}",
       to: "${mailRecipients}",
       replyTo: "${mailRecipients}",
       recipientProviders: [[$class: 'CulpritsRecipientProvider']]
   }
   ```

Comment: I know this is an old post but I am trying the same ( to send cppcheck reports by email) and I found this template I wanted to try, I just created a file.template in `$JENKINS_HOME\email-templates` and then added a stage like this to my pipeline `emailext( mimeType: 'text/html', body: '${SCRIPT, template="my_email.template"}', subject: "[Jenkins] ${jobName}", to: "${mailRecipients}")` but instead of receiving the template I receive a the string `${SCRIPT, template="my_email.template"}`

Comment: @JesusFernandez Have you tried wrapping it in 3 single quotation marks, like in the example above?

Comment: yes I have, but I have just realized I am trying to send a jelly script not an html so I guess this does not work for me (it is my first time using this plugin...)

Comment: how to use conditionals in this , this didn't work for me ```if ( "${env.MY_ENV}" == "true" ) { %>```

Answer (score 1):

It's a pretty old thread but here's what I did to make use of the built in template do this

```
    stage('Send Email')
    {
        steps
        {
            emailext body: '${JELLY_SCRIPT,template="html"}',recipientProviders: [[$class: 'DevelopersRecipientProvider'], [$class: 'RequesterRecipientProvider']], subject: 'Build Successful ${JOB_NAME}',mimeType: 'text/html'
        }
                
    }
```

The Plugin Documentation states that the html Jelly script is built in so you can easily make use of it.

https://plugins.jenkins.io/email-ext/

Answer (score -2):

The answer is, in fact, blatantly obvious, and included in the email-ext documentation:

```
${SCRIPT, template="groovy-text.template"}
```

Comment: The documentation is poorly written, judging by the number of questions people are asking. There are no examples on how to use this line in your Jenkinsfile. Simply entering this line will cause the "unexpected token: SCRIPT" error, so could you please provide an example of how to use this line?

Comment: I'm afraid this was ages ago and I can't even remember which project this was for but I have vague memories of using it in the box for the email contents which you access via the Jenkins web UI. Sorry I can't be more helpful.